# What is the different between gdata.client and gdata.service inside gdata-python-client?

Tags: python, gdata, gdata-python-client

When i was reading both, they seems targeting the same thing and written by the same author.
So what is the different between those two?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `service.py` module was used for a `v1` implementation of the library, which was greatly improved by introducing `client.py` for a `v2` implementation. Most (if not all) of the remaining GData APIs use **only** the `client` implementation.

From the [source](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/src/gdata/client.py) of `client.py`:

```
"""Provides a client to interact with Google Data API servers.

This module is used for version 2 of the Google Data APIs. The primary class
in this module is GDClient.

  GDClient: handles auth and CRUD operations when communicating with servers.
  GDataClient: deprecated client for version one services. Will be removed.
"""
```